# What is the best solution to simulate the "IN" operator in Javascript to simplify redundant logical ORs

Tags: javascript

I have an Ajax request that can return more than one valid value, so i am using the "OR" operator to analyse the response, like this:

```
if(json.reply == "d" || json.reply == "e" || json.reply == "i" || json.reply == "j" || json.reply == "k" )
```

My real code has more comparisons yet, so is there a more readable and elegant sintaxe in Javascript to write this? Something like the SQL "IN" operator:

```
if( json.reply IN ("d", "e", "i", "j", "k") )
```

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: If you're only working with strings, make a string to represent all values with a delimiter, then use `.indexOf` on the string, which has much wider support than a `Array.prototype.indexOf`. `var vals = "d,e,i,j,k,"; if (vals.indexOf(json.reply + ',') != -1) { ...` You can get rid of the `","` delimiter if there's not possibility of false positives.

Comment: @MarcioSimao Don't you think that the way we write `json.reply.IN("d","e","i","j","k");` with my answer is better?

Comment: @Mageek, Your function is good, but in my case i want a solution with native Javascript, without create a function. Thanks for your suggestion, upvote to you! Just one doubt, in your function isn't missing the argument of the function called `il`?

Comment: @MarcioSimao There was an typo (`;` instead of `,`), I corrected it. But `il` wasn't an argument, it's a variable that contains the length of arguments(not to re-calculate it for each iteration). See http://www.openjs.com/articles/for_loop.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switch statement is another possible way:

```
switch (varName)
{
case "mike": case "joe": case "larry": 
alert('cool');
break;

default: 
alert('also cool');
break;
}
```

Comment: It isn't so simple and elegant as the SQL "IN" operator, but is readable and is native of the language, what will ensure a good compatibility. Thanks for your suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

You could make an array of all allowed answers, and then see if the reply is in that array.

```
var allowedReplies = ["d", "e", "i", "j", "k"];

if(allowedReplies.indexOf(json.reply) != -1) {
  // your other code
}
```

Note that `indexOf` is not in all versions of IE, though. According to MDN it shows up in IE9. You can easily write your own implementation for the versions that don't have it, especially if you're using jQuery (I did this same thing for one of my projects).

Comment: It is a option, but doing some searches a saw that indexOf was just added in ECMAScript 5 and because of this is not implemented in every browser, so i am trying to find a solution with more compatibility

Comment: @masimao Jquery has the [inArray](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) function

Answer (score 1):

You can reprogram the function like this:

```
function IN()
{
    var exist=0;
    for(var i=0,il=arguments.length;i<il;i++)
        if(arguments[0]==arguments[i])
            exist=1;
    return exist;
}
```

You call the function like this : `IN(json.reply,"d","e","i","j","k");`

Here is a fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/mageek/TwCKC/3

**EDIT:**

The same function, but called differently:

```
function IN()
{
    var exist=0;
    for(var i=0,il=arguments.length;i<il;i++)
        if(this!=arguments[i])
            exist=1;
    return exist;
}
String.prototype.IN=IN;
Number.prototype.IN=IN;
Object.prototype.IN=IN;
```

Then you call it like this : `json.reply.IN("d","e","i","j","k");`

And the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/mageek/TwCKC/2

Answer (score 1):

```
    if(json.reply in {d:1,e:1,i:1,j:1,k:1}){

or

    if({d:1,e:1,i:1,j:1,k:1}[json.reply]){
```

Comment: Sweet, even though $.inArray (and similar wrappings around potentially missing Array.indexOf) should work faster. Still +1 for the 'hashing' mindset. )

Answer (score 0):

Use [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf). It'll return the index of the letter found, or -1 if it didn't find it.

```
["d", "e", "i", "j", "k"].indexOf("i")
> 2
["d", "e", "i", "j", "k"].indexOf("a")
> -1
```

Comment: It is a option, but doing some searches a saw that indexOf was just added in ECMAScript 5 and because of this is not implemented in every browser, so i am trying to find a solution with more compatibility

Comment: @masimao you can always run https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim and not worry about it.

Comment: "indexOf is a recent addition to the ECMA-262 standard; as such it may not be present in all browsers. You can work around this by inserting the following code at the beginning of your scripts, allowing use of indexOf in implementations which do not natively support it." On [that page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf#Compatibility) it has the code.

Comment: Instead of doing indexOf on an array, you could do it on a String: "deijk".indexOf("i"). Of course, this is assuming that "d", "e", etc. are the real values you are branching on.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the possible lack of `indexOf` use a regex:

```
var allowed = ["a","b","c","d"];
if (RegExp("^("+allowed.join("|")+")$").test(json.reply)){
    console.log('allowed');
    }
```

If your allowed replies may contain regex quantifiers etc then you'll want to escape them first.